# Should I be casting as a boolean or fake a boolean?

Tags: php, syntax

If I get an integer variable (anywhere from `0`+) There are a few things I can do to make sure the number is **not** `0`(zero):

- Option 1:

  ```
  if($number > 0){
      // number is not zero
  }
  ```
- Option 2:

  ```
  if($number){
      // number is not zero
  }
  ```
- Option 3:

  ```
  if((bool) $number){
      // number is not zero
  }
  ```
- Option 4:

  ```
  if(!!$number){
      // number is not zero
  }
  ```
- Etcetera....

Which one of the above is considered really the best to do?
Or is there an even better option?

Comment: Option 2 seems as if it is the best, because you can be absolutely certain that it won't be zero in that case. Although, I would assume it is simply an implicit boolean cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the *identical* [comparison operaton](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), which does not do any type juggling (and is faster).

```php
if ($number !== 0) {
 //         ^^^
 // Number is not identical to 0
}
```

***Note:** This is assuming the variable is actually a "integer variable", and not a string that happens to contain a number.*

```
if (false == ($number === 0)) {
 //                   ^^^
 // It is false that Number is identical to 0
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is an option. but why choose that over anything else?!

Comment: Because all other options involve conversion, I suppose?

Comment: Because it's the literal comparison. Also you could try the: if (0!==$number) to ensure that your number is not zero always (if that's what you want).

Comment: Note that you should probably not use the strict operator unless you are absolutely certain it is not a string.

Comment: @LeviMorrison: The question explicitly asks about an integer variable. So it's not a string and we can be absolutely certain about that fact.

Comment: @hakre, and you're assuming the OP is using the word `integer` to apply specifically to the `int` type, rather than (incorrectly in this case) using it to reference a numeric value that is an 'integer' (a natural number). Due to type juggling, many users of PHP don't realize there is a difference between `'0'` and `0`, so it's always a good idea to specify that there *is* a difference.

Comment: OP wrote *"integer variable"*  so I'm pretty sure it's the (variable) type, not a rough description of a number me and you use without computers.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used this:

```
if(!empty($number)){
 // Number is not 0
}
```

I think of it as two birds with one stone.

- Variable set.
- Not `0`

Comment: In most cases, it isn't a good idea to do both checks at once (especially to use this as the go to solution for checking that an integer isn't 0), as you often want an error to be thrown if the variable doesn't exist yet. Using this can cause an error to go through without notice (because `$number` not existing is treated as `0`).

Comment: @bfrohs, I guess you're right, I think I've used it a lot mainly because most of the time I needed to do both checks. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($number != 0){
 // Number is not 0
}
```